# iis web service or what, change method result

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a web service on iis. service must return like 34.56 string value. Because in my local service return this value, but when i try this method on iis server methot return 34560000.
What is the reason of this problem?

```
 public string GetTotal(string a, string b)
    {
        double total= 0;
        List<BorcLite> bList = GetTotalList(a, b);

        if (bList.Count == 0)
            return total.ToString();

        if (bList[0].resultCode != "0")
            return bList[0].resultCode; 

        foreach (BorcLite record in bList)
        {
            total+= Convert.ToDouble(record.totalBill);
        }
        return total.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Probably different locales being used on 2 machines, and `Convert.ToDouble` uses the current thread culture. Try using `Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or whatever culture you require

Comment: Yah seems to be a locale issue

Comment: thank you so much Zdeslav Vojkovic :) It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToDouble` uses current thread culture.
You probably use different locales on your systems.

Solution is to use appropriate culture by calling the overload of `Convert.ToDouble`  which takes `IFormatProvider` as argument:

```
string s = "34,56000";
double d = Convert.ToDouble(s); // my default US -> 3456000
d = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // -> 3456000
d = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); // -> 3456000
d = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")); // -> 34.56
```